# Setting wmode for HTML element overlays of jwplayer using javascript

Tags: javascript, overlay, transparent, jwplayer, wmode

I am trying to overlay a `<div>` on my jwplayer. I believe in order to do this, I have to set the 'wmode' parameter to be 'transparent.' So far I've been unsuccessful trying it this way:

```
jwplayer('profile-video').setup(
                'width': '640',
                'height': '360',
                'skin' : "/jwplayer/skins/bekle.xml",
                'file' : video_url,
                'wmode' : 'transparent'
            )
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong or maybe 'wmode' is the wrong parameter to be setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine too, but the best way to really overlay a div on top of a JW Player is via a JavaScript plugin. We have a SDK available here with a sample Hello World JS based plugin - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: Do you know if this only applies to the flash version?

Comment: Works in both Flash and HTML5 :)

Comment: I downloaded your "settable wmode" example and tried to move a `<div>` to overlay the `transparent` jwplayer but the player still covered it.

Comment: That example is for JW5, not 6, and per my answer above, the official way to overlay a div on top of the player is via a JS plugin. If you download the SDK there is a JS plugin which works in Flash and HTML5 mode called helloworld.js which indeed overlays a div over the player.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what wmode is for? From my experience with the YouTube player, I thought the idea was that setting wmode=transparent allowed you to have other html elements display over the player. But that doesn't seem to be the behavior for the jwplayer. Anyway, I downloaded the plugin and was able to have that produce text. Super-convenient, lol.

Comment: wmode is only part of it. You also need to mess with css, position, and z-index, but since our plugins api already takes care of that, that is why I recommended it ;) Glad you got it working!

Comment: Ethan, your link seems to be outdated. Where do you download the SDK?

Comment: Hi Ethan, I have used the below plugin 
github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks/tree/master/jw6-plugin-sdk 
for showing overlay. It woks fine for html mode. But in flash it works if player is in normal size , when the I maximize the player overlay is not showing. Currently I'm using 6.12 version. Can you help this out.?

Comment: You need to provide a link to your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://totaldev.com/content/jw-player-textmark-plugin.

This plugin has a flexibility to have multiple text overlays.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.